# Storing a number greater than 20! (factorial)

Tags: c

I am trying to find the numbers till `100!` (factorial) but after `20!` it gives an error as the value is too large to handle.  How can I store such a number?

Comment: Floating-point or multi-precision library...

Comment: What do you plan to do with the factorial afterwards?

Comment: First thing, that comes to my mind for such questions - why `C`? You need this as a part of something bigger, or you just need the values? Because `python` or `scheme` or many other languages will do this for you extremely fast and without any problems.

Comment: Use GMP, the GNU Multi Precision library. I hacked together [this](https://gist.github.com/iwillspeak/5374227) to compute factorials with it a while ago.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

20 factorial is 19 digits long.
100 factorial is 158 digits long, taking up 500 bits! It's actually:

```
933262154439441526816992388562667004907159682643816214685929638952175999932299156089414639761565182862536979208272237582511852109168640000000000000000
00000000
```

None of the standard types will work for you here, what you'll have to do is implement your own routine for handling such large numbers.

For example you will need to accept that multiplying two 32 bit values together may result in a 64 bit result.

This was coommon practice for calculating large numbers in the days of 8 bit processors.
Its referred to as [arbitrary precision arithemtic.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

[Here](http://www.8052.com/mul16.php)'s a link to describe how this was done. Admittedly it's for assembler, but it still holds true here. You'll need to take into account the default sizes of `int` on your system.

Answer (score 10):

At least on Linux, a possible multi-precision library could be [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) (it also works on Solaris, Windows, MacOSX, etc...).

Comment: And for more libraries, Wikipedia has a nice list for different languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries

Answer (score 1):

How would you do it on paper?
Doing multiplications with numbers 160-digits long is not that hard for a computer.

Try writing your own function or use an existing library.

Comment: I would write this as comment. No offence :)

Comment: I'm not sure that naive approaches are enough. I did read quickly a book on multi-precision arithmetic, and the actual algorithms are much better -complexity wise- than naive ones, but are absolutely non-intuitive. (the math involved is non-trivial). Also, actual implementations may use machine-specific (e.g. some assembly code for addition with carry, ...) or system-specific tricks

Comment: Basile: I agree, but Rishabh (the OP) is, apparently, a newcomer to programming. Writing his own function would be a fun learning experience. @Kiril: no offence taken.

Answer (score -3):

This code will help up to `170!`. Use double for the factorial function, because normal int or long int will not support that factorial result, double will support up to `1.7e308`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double fact(int k){
    int i;
    double f=1;
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++) f=f*i;
    return (f);
}
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=65;i++)
    printf("%d! = %.3lf\n",i,fact(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question